# What are the different types/levels of consciousness in the experiencing of feelings?

Tags: philosophy-of-mind, consciousness

What type of consciousness is the mere experience of having a feeling.  So one has a feeling of anger, happiness, excitement, etc.  By the word "mere," I mean the feeling is not reflected on; we have it, but not think about it to any degree; we just "have it".  Intuitively speaking, this type of experience (of a feeling) I think this would be called "subconscious" experience, but in terms of philosophy of mind I am not sure.
Is the experience I outline an instance "phenomenal consciousness," and the bringing of the feeling into refection is "meta-awareness"?